# Problems adding WCF Data Services to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, wcf, odata

I would like to **add a custom OData endpoint to SharePoint 2010**.

Because of its dependency on .NET 4.0, the [Web API OData provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443465/which-odata-provider-to-use) is currently not an option for SharePoint 2010 (based on .NET 3.5). Therefore I am attempting to use the [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) even though it is a 'dead' project (last update was May 2011).

I followed [these instructions](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html) which rely on the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.**ServerRuntime** to provide the hosting support alleviating the need to modify web.config. However, after deploying my SharePoint WSP to my server, and trying to access the new WCF service, I get the following error:

> The type 'Company.Services.CapturxData, CapturxOData, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=590c8a9e4250b98a', provided as the
>   Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be
>   found.

even though the CapturxOData assembly is loaded into the W3WP.exe process and the type is correctly referenced in my CapturxData.svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Service="Company.Services.CapturxData, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
%>
```

Are there additional configuration steps or configuration options to be set for this scenario to work? Or is there another way to add a custom OData provider to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: here is a detailed instruction: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have a code sample that exposes the Web Property Bag as a custom ODATA web service in SharePoint 2010 using the Data Service Host Factory. I didn't need to use any toolkits. I believe the purpose of the toolkit was to provide support for dynamic entities. Deploy the .svc file under the ISAPI folder - I didn't have to modify any web.config settings.

Here are the code snippets. Let me know if this helps. The service is part of a project with a bunch of other stuff. If you have trouble getting it running, let me know and I can try to package it up as a Visual Studio project.

http://goo.gl/SPQqA